# Find tags *ML style using regex java

Tags: java, regex

I am facing some troubles using regex groups in java trying to find (X/XHT/HT/*)ML tags, the purpose of this is removing them from the file, this is what I have (this is only for the comment tag, but if i understand this the others shouldn't be a problem)

```
final String PATTERN = "(\\<\\!\\-\\-).*(\\-\\-\\>)";
```

I also have use some variants of this because of course the comment could be after some code or  in the middle or at the end which would be adding more `.*` or alike, but my real problem is trying to understand how the grouping works, for example using this if I use the function `find` in a line with more than one comment it finds the first group starting whit the first comment opening and ending at the latest comment close, this is:

```
String lineToTry = "text <!-- bla bla --> some more text <!-- second comment --> some more text again"
```

in this case it finds as the first group this:

```
<!-- bla bla --> some more text <!-- second comment -->
```

when I was expecting it to find just

```
<!--
```

Then i would try to find group two:

```
-->
```

then I would move my find pointer (`find(indexOfEndOfPreviousOccurence)`) to the index of the end of the previous line and find again group one.

I am a bit stuck with this, I hope you be able to help me understand this since java documentation (at least [the one I've read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html#backref) is not that specific about groups in regex)

I would appreciate if you have any other better solution, but still I would like you to help me understand why this is happening, but both are welcome :)

Comment: Why you escaped `-`, `>`, `<`, `!` ?

Comment: because all of those are used for other purposes as mentioned in java documentation for regex `The metacharacters supported by this API are: <([{\^-=$!|]})?*+.>` (from: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html )

Comment: seems like there is a need to edit the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(<!--).*?(-->)
```

Add `?` to make your `*` non greedy.Or else by default `*` is greedy and will not stop at the first instance of `(-->)` but will stop at the last instance.`?` makes it non greedy and will stop at the first instance `(-->)`.

Comment: man I love you, and your quick answer, I didn't know it was greedy expression I don't understand how come that I didn't think of that!, but still could you explain to me how comes that if finds as the first group the whole <!-- bla bla --> and not just <!-- ? ...

Comment: @Ordiel youre welcome :) because you have `.*?` `.` will match anything between your two groups.So `bla bla` will be matched and in fact anythin between your two groups will be matched.`<!--` was not getting matched as you had `.*` in your regex will will consume all and stop at last instance of `-->`.

Comment: the thing is that if I remove the `.*?` it finds no group at all

Comment: Oh, you are right!, i got confuse because a print line I had, sorry hehehe

Comment: but still group(1) return <!-- bla bla -->  not just <!-- and I do not know why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64149/discussion-between-vks-and-ordiel).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a non-greedy regex:

```
(<!--).*?(-->)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sC3wE0/1)

**PS:** Btw there is no need to use all those escapes as in your regex.

Answer (score 0):

I try this regex take if necessary.

```
  (<!--)(?:(?!(<!--)|(-->)).)*(-->)
```

**SEE DEMO** : http://regex101.com/r/sC3wE0/2